# How can I complete the quest "Taking Care of Business" for the Thieves Guild if Bersi is dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was walking into his shop and talking to him, when out of nowhere vampires jumped out and they killed Bersi in the process. Now the quest is still ongoing, even though I've looted everything that he owns and smashed all the urns (including in Riften and the Hall of the Dead where his body is).

I've done everything I could do and even resurrected him as a zombie. How can I complete this quest?

Comment: What quest are you talking about? Might help to add that.

Comment: Taking care of buissness for the theifs guild offered by brynjolf

Comment: You should edit that into the question

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Try [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/294396/edit)

Comment: Ok thanks for help but can u anwser the question?

Comment: Yeah, let me see what I can do

Comment: console or PC? If console, which one?

Comment: Console ps4 (remastered)

Comment: All right, see my answer. It looks like you'll just have to reload a previous save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are playing on console, it seems like you're out of luck. Bersi will need to be *alive* to finish `Taking Care of Business`, so you'll have to reload a save from before he died.

If you are on PC, you can use console commands to bring him back to life. I'm not too familiar with console commands for Skyrim, but it looks like you hit <kbd>~</kbd> then click on Bersi, then enter `resurrect`.

Comment: Ok thanks i guess i will just have to deal with it bc im not going back 20 lvls

Comment: @GefaultPlayz, sorry there wasn't a better solution for you

Comment: @GefaultPlayz A good general rule for the future: if a named NPC gets killed in a random event (e.g. dragon or vampire attack), before doing anything else, look up that person's name on a wiki like UESP, and see if they are required for any quests, or have radiant quest bugs associated with them. If they do, reload your most recent save, do the random encounter again and try to avoid having that person get killed (or try to avoid the encounter altogether). It's a shame that it needs to be done, but it's the best way to avoid bugs like this, especially when playing on a console.